# Copying Template Worksheet after Specific Range of Worksheet Names

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to store a list of worksheet names in a range and copy an OrderSummary Template sheet after those names in Range("C2:C5"). However... I am not able to figure out how to store/reference this range in this line of code:

```
wp.Activate: wp.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

In my mind i want it to work something like wp.Activate: wp.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets("Range").Range("C2:C5").. and copy after each of the named worksheets in that range but I just can not get this to work... Here is what I have thus far...

**My only issue is that I can not copyafter the correct worksheets in my workbook..otherwise my code is working!**

```
Sub OrderSummary():
Dim s As String, O As String, PID As String, PName As String, PSize As String, PQuan As Integer
Dim eF As Long, i As Long, r As Long, WI As Workbook, wp As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range


Set WI = Workbooks("260 Sale Template"):
Set ws = WI.Worksheets("PackingSlipTable"): ws.Activate
Set wp = Workbooks("Packing Slip FIXED").Worksheets("Order Group")


eF = ws.Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To eF
If Range("T" & i) = O Then GoTo Products
                        r = 0
                    
O = Range("T" & i):
u = Range("U" & i):
w = Range("W" & i):
x = Range("X" & i):
y = Range("Y" & i):
Z = Range("Z" & i):

Set rng = Worksheets("Range").Range("C2:C5")

For Each cell In rng
    wp.Activate: wp.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Order Group" & " " & O
Products:
    PID = ws.Range("L" & i)
    PName = ws.Range("N" & i): PQuan = ws.Range("M" & i)
    PBin = ws.Range("K" & i):
    POrder = ws.Range("A" & i)
    
                If r Then GoTo PostProducts
    
FillSlip: r = 8
Range("C" & r + 7) = O
    Range("F1") = O
    Range("A4") = u
    Range("B4") = Z
    Range("E4") = w
    Range("E5") = x
    Range("E6") = y
    
PostProducts:
    r = r + 1: Workbooks("Packing Slip FIXED").Activate
    Range("A" & r) = PID:
    Range("B" & r) = PName & " "
    Range("E" & r) = PQuan
Range("F" & r) = PBin
    Range("G" & r) = POrder
    ws.Activate
Next cell
Next i:

End Sub
```

Comment: An important side note... the use of `GoTo` is discouraged as it creates spaghetti code.

Comment: Would you have any suggestions on how I can make this more efficient?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what logic you're intending with `If r Then`... that's implicit conversion of a `Long` to a `Boolean`.

Comment: The second half (Fill Slip and PostProducts) simply allow me to fill out my template sheet with the order summary items.. I have not really experienced any issues with the code through 3000-4000 sheets made...other than a large excel file! Would you have any idea how to solve my Range of sheet names issue?

Comment: Use a loop through each cell in that range to grab the appropriate worksheet names one by one.

Comment: Would the worksheet loop be on top of my loop with "i" or nested inside?

Comment: Nested inside..

Comment: Am I somewhat in the right area? I am a bit confused on how to do this...I made an edit to the post